# Interfacing Hadoop to Cassandra on Amazon AWS - netty version conflict?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, netty, amazon-emr

I've got a Hadoop map reduce class that runs on Amazon EMR and outputs to an HDFS flatfile.  All well and good, but now I need to output to a Cassandra DB, also running on AWS.  I built and ran a local client and got that working, then moved the Cassandra writing code to my Hadoop project.  The problem, it seems, is that Amazon draws in  `/home/hadoop/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar` for Hadoop 1.0.3, but the Cassandra that runs on AWS is 1.2.6 and uses `netty-3.5.9.Final.jar`.

What can I do to prevent or circumvent this conflict?  Can I draw in my newer version of netty along side the one Amazon EMR draws in?

The error I get from running the jar on EMR is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.<init>(IIIIIZ)V
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Frame$Decoder.<init>(Frame.java:147)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$PipelineFactory.getPipeline(Connection.java:616)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:212)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:111)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:56)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:387)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:211)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:174)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:87)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:609)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$100(Cluster.java:553)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:67)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:94)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:534)
    at GraphAnalysis.MatrixBuilder.compileOutput(MatrixBuilder.java:282)
    at GraphAnalysis.MatrixBuilder.main(MatrixBuilder.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with one of our internal modules which had used netty-3.2.4.jar which had a missing  function.

Ultimately I had to do open-heart surgery on the jar file.

1. Expand the jar file that embeds the old netty library using `jar
   -xvf oldlibrary.jar`
2. Delete the folder org/jboss/netty.
3. Then expand the new netty jar file into a separate folder
4. Copy the new org/jboss/netty folder along with its contents to the old location `cp -prf netty .`
5. Create a new JAR package `jar -cvf ../new_jarfile.jar *`

This is a rare case, but you can apply this method to overcome library incompatibilities whenever they occur. Make sure that your program still runs. If you change the underlying library this way, there are changes that your original program will not run. A well-designed library should be agnostic of such changes though.